# ExtJs - Dynamic Ext.panel.Panel in one page

Tags: extjs, ext-panel

I have few Panels in my page, being created dynamically regarding the type of data that should be presenting.
I'd like to add checkbox to the title row of a particular panel. I identify this panel by it's properties (like it's name\ title and fields count).Then I add the checkbox like that:

```
newPanel.header.items = [
   {
      xtype: 'checkbox',
      boxLabel: 'some text'
   }
 ];
```

But for some reason, this checkbox is being render to all panels in the page.
I'm sure that the above code happening only once - I've put an alert to check that.
Can I avoid it and make the checkbox appears only on one specific panel?
Can someone point out that why checkbox appears in all of my dynamic panels there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the "add" method or the "setItems" method of the parent container (your header container I suppose), ie:

```
var myPanel = Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel');

var myHeader = Ext.create('Ext.container.Container');

myPanel.add(myHeader);

myHeader.add({xtype: 'checkbox'});
```

Comment: Adding a checkbox to my container will place it in my container's header, isn't it?

Comment: header and footer are part of the panel (a panel is a container with more features). details here: http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0/6.0.2-classic/#!/api/Ext.panel.Panel

Comment: I add the checkbox to header of panel. there are 2 more panels below, but the checkbox is being placed there two. Is it because they all are under the same container? Is header common between some panels?

Comment: I don't understand, create a fiddle here https://fiddle.sencha.com to show your problem

Comment: I've created one for you, take a look here https://fiddle.sencha.com/?fiddle=1907#fiddle/1907 if this answers your question please accept, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try below code

```
newPanel.getHeader().add({
    xtype: 'checkbox',
    boxLabel: 'Some Text'
});
```

Here is [Fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/1908) for your reference.